# Is there angst and factionation here, more than most other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if there is a fool-proof angst-o-meter for SE yet, but the way new users with low reputation are treated can serve as a facsimile.

My last three questions were roller-coaster rides. Two of the three were met with answers that were then deleted and followed by close votes by the individual who withdrew their answer. *I've asked nearly a thousand questions in stackexchange*, and I've only seen this happen three times total.

My most recent [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/405336/217285) (where this happened) also shows two up votes, and my score is 19. This means five up votes and three down votes.

I was also a victim of a [serial down-vote session](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10615/217285), a kind of [voter fraud](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10616/217285). The SE system seems to have automatically reversed 4 of the 6 soon afterward.

On the meta question [My question is not so well received, why?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10510/217285) , two active users here nearly simultaneously posted answers and fired off further comments directed at me under each others questions, while simultaneously posting comments directed to me under my original question. It turns out I had given links to three high quality answers here in English SE for a definition of a term, instead of pasting the definition explicitly, and apparently this is not considered best practice here. A single, simple helpful comment could have cleared that up, rather than the barrage of (now deleted) comments I received under the [original question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/399555/217285).

Based on my experience, asking questions here is painful and angsty for new users, but that's just my perspective. It seems like there are nice people (remember "be nice"?) and mean people. Pardon my use of child-like terms, but they fit. So angsty and factionated.

Is this only my impression, or has there been some other recognition and discussion of this potential problem?

- [“Marking a question as duplicate … except when a question is closed as a duplicate…”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/394796/217285)
- [Is the object in “Eighty-six forty-five.” a proper noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/399555/217285)
- [The 'de' in indefatigable](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/405336/217285)

Comment: Looking at your two specific questions, it seems there was a bit of of overzealousness and/or literality in the close voters, using close reasons as strict rules rather than suggestions. Is that a trend (or constant feeling) on ELU? Possibly. Everybody thinks they're an expert on English because they speak it. That's like everybody thinking they are dietitians because they eat.

Comment: The "Eighty-six forty-five" question (which your "another question" link links to) has only ever had one answer. That question has had 15 comments deleted, thirteen by a moderator.

Comment: @AndrewLeach thanks for your help, I've edited the paragraph. I believe there were two users, two questions and two answers under one of them that resulted in comments effectively coming at me from up-to four directions at once, but with only memory and no screenshots to reconstruct it, I remember trying to patiently respond to it all but not all of the details.

Comment: As for "nice" or "mean," and the general angsty feeling a new user might experience, [I like J.R.'s Thanksgiving analogy answer here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10520/228732).

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime thanks for that! I've been a "new user" on many sites, so I'm asking not about being a new user, but about a differential, thus the "...more than most other SE sites?" But I really like the analogy. Indeed, entering any "new room" in the SE house feels a lot like sitting down with an extended, emotive family that one is unfamiliar with.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime It does indeed, thanks! Sometimes I add small reinforcements of the theme to keep subsequent comments from keying off of a minor point and diverging. I know what you mean and it's a nice read.

Comment: It's uhm weird to see that all linked meta posts have my answers accepted. I feel cornered. Hmmm.. :\

Comment: @NVZ In the last 60 days there have been about 100 questions in meta. You've posted 37 meta answers in the same time period. Your answers are frequently accepted. Combine that with the fact that I try to make sure to accept the best answer, and it's not surprising that the accepted answers of two out of two linked questions are yours.

Comment: Ah, fair point. You made my day. :)

Comment: A barrage of comments? The comments were there to help explain why the post had been downvoted. Your stubborn refusal to even acknowledge that commenters may have raised a valid point and your stubborn refusal to listen to users who have been contributing to the site for years and care about good questions and answers doesn't redeem you.  I suppose you would prefer anonymous downvoting, duly noted. For the sake of clarity,  I never downvoted the 8645 question, I spent my time being helpful.

Comment: On the topic of revenge voting, anytime you believe you are a victim of serial downvoting, please wait at least 48 hours, if nothing happens,  flag the behavior to the mod team. Users who serial downvote will normally be suspended. (I would say "always" but I'm not 100% certain)

Comment: I have no idea why your question *The 'de' in indefatigable* has received 4 DVs. That is crazy and inexplicable.

Comment: The reversal action is usually performed within 24 hours, but there's no harm in waiting two days before flagging suspicious behavior. You were lucky that the reversal took minutes, that is not my personal experience. And it would be unrealistic to expect the team or a bot to react so instantaneously. If you look on [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), you're bound to find more precise information.

Comment: @Mari-LouA where does 48 hours come from? Is that a standard rule-of-thumb? The SE bot took action in minutes, so I wonder if the 48 hours would be to allow for a subsequent human review of the situation by the SE team or the moderators? The problem with doing nothing for 48 hours, and this is exacerbated for low reputation users like myself, is that down votes can attract more, reflexive down votes, and both of those can then attract reflexive close votes. Here reflexive means "knee-jerk". Thus, it is important — especially for new, low-rep users — take action quickly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'll look, thanks! I had to re-post my comment which leaves it out of sequence because I had to search the internet for an em-dash (blush) and that pushed me beyond the five minute edit limit. I type fast but edit slow. But I have to reiterate that for low reputation users, there is likely to be harm in waiting. With low rep, down votes hurt more, both existentially and quantitatively, and I have a hunch that the reflexive close votes come quicker as well. All of this is just less of an issue once reputation rises. I notice this more than most because I've been a new user frequently

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting/28758#28758 ( Posted in 2009, so its outdated but it's still interesting to read) This one was posted in 2013 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed

Comment: If the post is reasonably good, users won't DV because they see a post already has two downvotes. They will if the question is explicitly off-topic, regardless if the first vote cast was dictated by revenge, which they wouldn't know in any case. A serial DVer cannot DV the same question more than once, if anyone's post has more than three DVs there's something wrong with the post itself... (usually)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I guess neither of us can know how thousands of users might or might not vote and why they do so. I'm pretty sure my "hunch" about the herd mentality model has some merit, and the "good SE citizen" model has merit as well. Most viewers of a given question don't vote at all, so the up and down buttons are often clicked by the most reactive "tails" of the distributions, in both up and down directions. Thank you for the [tech-savvy use of links](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10511/217285) and engaging discussion; I'll take the bold step of clicking on them and take a look.

Comment: ERRATA CORRIGE "Users who serial downvote will normally be suspended." Not so. Today I found out that users who have been tempted to engage in revenge DVing, or are naturally inclined to be malicious, are not necessarily suspended. In fact, they may even be repeated offenders, the SE bot does not suspend users, which is one reason why flagging repeated suspicious behavior becomes very important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If comments or answers are unprofessional/uncollegiate in tone, please feel free to throw a flag. The moderation team strongly supports the Be Nice policy.

Comment: While not precisely an answer, it's good advice; let the SE system work its magic, (making thousands of people play nice on the internet and helping them learn from each other).